# Downloading in utorrent without internet connection

Tags: networking, internet-connection, utorrent

[image]

My network connection uses dial-up method for internet access but in this strange case without dialing, utorrent is downloading vmware software?

At the bottom right side corner you can see exclamation mark in the internet icon that shows the internet access is off.

> And, two times I got warning from KIS 2013 that there has been network
>   spoofing.

**1. What is the reason for this ?**

**2. Should I delete that file and re-download it?**

Answer (score 2):

At least one of your assumptions is not correct. you must have an internet connection if you are downloading. Keep in mind, the yellow triangle does not usually mean that the connection is down, but that there is some problem with it, and often those problems do not interfere with all processes. its possible that you have multiple network gateways, but my guess is you have an existing dialup session that is still in use.

The connection spoofing message is likely caused by dialing in to the modem bank at your ISP and getting a response from a new modem that KIS doesn't recognize.

Comment: But I haven't dialed my internet connection!!

Comment: not today perhaps. try pinging www.google.com . Dialup connections don't always disconnect if there is an established flow in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have a yellow triangle on the internet connection icon on the right lower side of the start menu and even though you cannot browse or surf internet through your browser apparently you can download torrent files from a torrent client. I am yet to understand how this works but it works anyway.